# Передача значения переменной Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Доброе времени суток сразу скажу ajax только изучаю но понадобилось передать значение переменой полученное при клике в php  переменную использовал jquery . итак вот
Index.php

```
}
else{ echo ("Данные не получены ")}?>
```

jquery

```
$(.link).click(function(){
   var ValLink=$(this).attr("value");
$.get( "index.php",{val1 : ValLink});});
```

Код не то чтобы не жизненный но не тот что используется реально (это я к тому что если гдето забыл поставить точкусзапятой или скобку в реальном коде все это не показывает как ошибку) причем заголовок показывает  GET http:// www.index.php/?val1=2. Но вот есно показывает что данные не переданыю, параметры value в жизни устанавливаются демонически. Может подскажите в чем ошибка? И как правильно сделать. 
оргигинальный код 
function.php

```
    add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3); //делаем миниатюру ссылкой 
function my_post_image_html($html, $post_id, $post_image_id) {
      $html = '<a href="'.get_permalink($post_id).
      '" title="'.esc_attr(get_post_field('post_title', $post_id)).
      '" value="'.$post_id.
      '/* получаем id*/ "class="kar_thumb">'.$html.
      '</a>';
      return $html;
  }
```

MyScript.js

```
jQuery('#carousel-rew .kar_thumb').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkRew = jQuery(this).attr("value");
    console.log(linkRew)
    jQuery.get(
        "../../../../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", {
            linkRew: linkRew
        });
});
```

кусок затрагиваемого кода index.php

```
<div class="inner">
<div class="text_title_rew">
    <h3>Отзывы</h3>
    <p>наших клиентов</p>
</div>
<div id="carousel-rew" class="sliderkit">
    <div class="sliderkit-nav">
        <div class="sliderkit-nav-clip">
            <ul>
                <?php $resultr=g et_category(59)->category_count; $args =array( 'showposts' => $resultr, 'cat' => '59'); $my_posts = get_posts($args); foreach ($my_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderkit-btn sliderkit-nav-btn sliderkit-nav-prev"><a href="#" title="Scroll to the left"><span>Previous</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderkit-btn sliderkit-nav-btn sliderkit-nav-next"><a href="#" title="Scroll to the right"><span>Next</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if (isset($_GET[ 'linkRew'])){ $theThumbPostId=$ _GET[ 'linkRew']; }else{ $theThumbPostId=948;} echo $theThumbPostId; ?>
<div class="text_rew">
    <?php $myposts=g et_posts( "include=$theThumbPostId"); foreach ($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>
    <div class="img_rew">
        <img src="<?php echo catch_that_image()?>">
    </div>
    <h3><?php the_title();?></h2></br>
                                    <div class="rew_list"><?php the_excerpt();?></div>
                                    <div class="rew_content"><?php the_content();?></div>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

код полностью вложил.

Comment: Приводите настоящий код. Этот просто не выполнится.

Comment: а вы не можете объяснить, почему не выполниться ?

Comment: параметры value в жизни устанавливаются демонически.

Comment: Блин если вас смущает value пусть это будет rel не суть в этом. Да и какое это программирование? Так попытки разработки.

Comment: > а вы не можете объяснить, почему не выполниться ?

не выполни**тс**я

Из-за синтаксических ошбиок: в php if идет вне php-тегов, поэтому появление else без предшествующего if выдаст ошибку; в js ошибку вызовет $(.link).

Не то чтобы из примера неясно, о чем идет речь, просто на первый взгляд все ок и проблема наверняка кроется в какой-нибудь мелочи.

Comment: Я выложил код полностью

Comment: Дошло. Вордпресс использует свою внутреннюю систему рерайтов, поэтому $\_GET-значения могут попросту исчезать. Вам нужно воспользоваться функцией [get_query_var()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) (внизу в документации есть заметка о том, как зарегистрировать собственную переменную).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".link").click( function() {
    var ValLink = $(this).attr("value");

    $.get(
        "index.php", 
        {val1 : ValLink},
        function(result) {
            // переменная result содержит результат выполнения PHP скрипта...
        });
    ...
```

Comment: тоесть вот это в функцию (result) передавать надо  (if (isset($_GET['val1 '])){<?php $LinkVal=$_GET['val1 '];
echo($LinkVal)}
) и все а как функцию вызывать ?

Comment: При нажатии на ссылку, скрипт получит ее значение value и отправит его с помощью JQuery PHP скрипту, а дальше вы уже сами решайте, что делать. Если нужно обработать результат выполнение PHP скрипта, то пишите код внутри той функции, где я написал коммент.
Что касается кода if (isset...) это нужно писать в самом PHP скрипте - index.php.